# Wireless USB Keyboard and Mouse not Detected Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, keyboard, mouse, logitech

I am having a problem with my newest installation of ubuntu on my Samsung Chromebox. As soon as I boot into the computer, the mouse and keyboard are not recognized. Mouse clicks/movement does not work. I cannot type. Both the mouse and keyboard are totally unresponsive. As soon as I grab a wired USB keyboard, the mouse works fine, but still not the keyboard. Both devices are Logitech.

Answer (score 1):

try to upgrade the kernel.. that might work.. do it with "sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty" I know that you're unable to type with your keyboard but you can copy and paste this command. This worked well to me for recognizing a usb webcam and my touch screen. It's about the drivers.